# Gravity Forms - Conditional merge tags - MULTIPLE Values in a single tag

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am using the Conditional Merge Tags shortcode in the form confirmation as found here: https://gravitywiz.com/gravity-forms-conditional-shortcode/

I've got a number field on the form where I ask people to input their age.

On the confirmation message, I'm using the merge tags to display a custom message based on the age input.

So for people who are younger than 18, I use shortcode with a message:

```
[gravityforms action="conditional" merge_tag="{my-field}" condition="less_than" value="18"]
You're too young.
[/gravityforms]
```

For people who are older than 55, I use shortcode with a message:

```
[gravityforms action="conditional" merge_tag="{my-field}" condition="greater_than" value="55"]
You're too old.
[/gravityforms]
```

Now I struggle to show the message to people who are between 18 - 55.

I'm trying to input multiple values from 18 to 55 with `condition="is"` like this:

```
[gravityforms action="conditional" merge_tag="{my-field}" condition="is" value="18, 19, 20, 21, ....... 54, 55"]
        You're the perfect age.
[/gravityforms]
```

But this doesn't work.

Is there any way I can use multiple values or specify something like is `greater_than` and `less_than` in the same single tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a snippet that makes Gravity Forms' conditional shortcode a little more robust:

https://gist.github.com/spivurno/9db18385ed1d1f11a897bdfa8a1f2007

With this snippet in your theme's functions.php file, you could write the logic like so:

````
[gravityforms action="conditional" relation="all"
value="{myField}" operator="greater_than" compare="18"
value2="{myField}" operator2="less_than" compare2="55"]
    You're the perfect age.
[/gravityforms]```
````

Comment: Hey David, thanks so much, this works perfectly! There is only one thing: when I use the shortcode in the confirmation message, I get the following notice: "Your confirmation message appears to contain a merge tag as the value for an HTML attribute. Depending on the attribute and field type, this might be a security risk."

Comment: Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: I have added the "sanitize message funtion" as per the help docs, so would adding the following snippet be enough?:
add_filter( 'gform_sanitize_confirmation_message', '__return_true' );

Comment: It looks like the GFFormSettings::confirmation_looks_unsafe() method is returning a false positive. Submit a support ticket to GF. I also work there so mention my name and whoever gets assigned can reach out for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional shortcode doesn't support multiple values or conditions at this time. However, you can create an additional confirmation for the 18-55 case, and use conditional logic on the confirmation itself.

Comment: Thanks @Naomi , that sounds like this might work, but how do I go about this? How would I use conditional logic on the confirmation? Or where would I create an additional confirmation for the 18-55 case?