# Gravity Forms - Nested conditional merge tags

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am using gravity forms and an addon called gravity PDF from Gravity Wiz. It allows to create PDF based on form entries. It allows 2 level of nested conditional tags, such as:

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYzxR.png)

I use a trick here. The tags are not the same (gravityform vs gravityforms). This trick allows 2 level of nested tags. I need 3 levels or more. Such as:

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2XDe.png)

But this doesn't work:

[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOZiL.png)

The closing tags got issues.

FYI :
https://docs.gravityforms.com/conditional-shortcode/
https://gravitywiz.com/gravity-forms-conditional-shortcode/

The support said me they are not going to add this feature so I need to find a workaround.

I read the post from Dave here: [Gravity Forms - Conditional merge tags - MULTIPLE Values in a single tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877419/gravity-forms-conditional-merge-tags-multiple-values-in-a-single-tag)

Looking into this filter may be the solution:

```
add_filter('gform_shortcode_conditional', function ($result, $atts, $content)
```

What would be the easiest solution? adding a custom tag (gravityform2) or comparing 2 values into one single tag?

```
[gravityforms action="conditional" relation="all"
value="{Occupation du logement:114}" operator="is" compare="était occupé à titre payant et que le précédent locataire l’a quitté depuis moins de 18 mois"
value2="{Dernier loyer du logement:115}" operator2="is" compare2="ce nouveau loyer est identique au précédent ou seulement révisé"]
    You're the perfect age.
[/gravityforms]
```

Someone can help?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877419/gravity-forms-conditional-merge-tags-multiple-values-in-a-single-tag is almost certainly the simpler option given your use-case. Are you having issues with it?

Comment: Yes.
This is what i use in the template: https://prnt.sc/s9ogth
And this is what I get in the PDF: https://prnt.sc/s9oh64

Comment: It looks good on the surface. We'd have to dig in deeper to figure out why it's not working for you. We're happy to provide that level of support for our snippets to Advanced and Pro Gravity Perks license-holders.

Comment: I only got a premium licence for gravity forms :/

Your snippet works only when there is only one condition in the template. If I have some more, it doesn't work.

Comment: Just bought it.

Comment: Awesome! If you haven't already, you should receive a response from our support team soon. 